# Is every module automorphism diagonalized by irreps?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ denote a finite group, and let $V$ be a complex and finite dimensional $G$ module; that is, there is a group representation $G\to GL(V)$. Finally, let $T\colon V\to V$ be an intertwining map, that is, a linear map such that $T(gv)=g T(v)$ for all $v\in V$ and $g\in G$.

By [the theorem of Maschke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem), there are irreducible $G$-modules $V_1, V_2, \ldots, V_n$ such that
$$
V=V_1\oplus V_2 \oplus \ldots \oplus V_n.$$

> **Question**. Is it true that
> $$T v_j=\lambda_j v_j, \qquad \forall v_j\in V_j,$$
> for some $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb C$?

The [lemma of Schur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma) says that this is the case provided that
$$\tag{*}T(V_j)\subset V_j.$$
This is because, in this case, $T$ restricts to an intertwining self-map of $V_j$, which is irreducible. Therefore such restriction must be a scalar multiple of the identity.

But is it true that (*) always holds with the given assumptions?

---

**EDIT**. This question arises from the following observations. Suppose that $G$ is finite and abelian, and let $L^2(G)$ denote the space of all complex-valued functions on $G$, which is a $G$-module with the representation $gf(x):=f(x-g)$. (This seemingly complicated notation hints at more general cases, with infinite groups).

Let $\chi\in L^2(G)$ denote a character, that is, a homomorphism of $G$ into $\mathbb C^\times$. Then an intertwining map $T\colon L^2(G)\to L^2(G)$ satisfies
$$T\chi=\lambda_\chi \chi, $$
as it is easy to prove. And since the irreps are in this case the 1-dimensional subspaces
$$
\operatorname*{span}(\chi), $$
it follows that intertwining maps **of the $G$-module $L^2(G)$** are diagonalized by irreps. (As the accepted answer clearly shows, intertwining maps of other $G$-modules need not be even diagonalizable! This is the reason why I found that answer surprising and enlightening).

Let us consider an infinite and non-abelian case. Suppose that $T\colon L^2(\mathbb S^{d-1})\to L^2(\mathbb S^{d-1})$ is rotation-invariant;
$$
(Tf)(R^{-1}x)=T(f(R^{-1}\cdot))(x).$$
Then $T$ is diagonalized by spherical harmonics. Precisely, letting
$$\{Y_{n, j}\ :\ j=1, \ldots, N(n)\}$$
denote a complete orthonormal system of spherical harmonics of degree $n$, we have that
$$
Tf=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda_n \sum_{j=1}^{N(n)} \hat{f}(n, j) Y_{n, j}, $$
where we have let $\hat{f}(n, j)$ denote the coefficient
$\langle f | Y_{n, j}\rangle.$

This latter example actually **is** a consequence of the lemma of Schur. Indeed, the decomposition of the $SO(d)$-module $L^2(\mathbb S^{d-1})$ into irreps is precisely
$$
\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty \operatorname*{span}\{ Y_{n,j}\ :\ j=1, \ldots, N(n)\}, $$
and these irreps are pairwise non-isomorphic, because $N(n)$ is not a constant. (Actually, $N(n)$ has a well-known combinatorial expression, which there is no need to write down explicitly here).

Comment: Not if $V_i\cong V_j$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng: Could you make an explicit example, please?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: The example with spherical harmonics should be exactly of the kind you suggested in the comments to the accepted answer. We have countably infinite irreps, but they are all non-isomorphic, hence intertwining maps are forced to be diagonal. I still think that this is the "natural" situation, in the sense that a "naturally arising" representation should satisfy this diagonalization, but I cannot make this any more precise.

Comment: I can make this more precise now. If $G$ is a group and $\chi\colon G\to \mathbb C$ is a group homomorphism, then an intertwining map $T\colon L^2(G)\to L^2(G)$ satisfies $T\chi=\lambda_\chi \chi$. ("Intertwining map" here means $Tf(g^{-1}x)=T(f(g^{-1}\cdot))(x)$). This is easy to prove, and it is the reason why in the abelian case intertwining maps OF THE $G$-module $L^2(G)$ are diagonal. Not of ANY $G$-module, as Omnomnomnom shows, but of $L^2(G)$. This is why, in Fourier analysis, translation-invariant operators tend to be diagonal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not necessarily true that $T(V_j) \subset V_j$ for all $j$. For instance, consider the representation of $G = \Bbb Z/n \Bbb Z$ given by
$$
\rho(k) = \pmatrix{\omega^k & 0\\0 & \omega^k},
$$
where $\omega$ is the $n$th root of unity $\omega = e^{2 \pi i / n}$. We note that in this case,
$$
T = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}
$$
is an intertwining map (in fact, so is any $T : \Bbb C^2 \to \Bbb C^2$).

Comment: In particular, intertwining maps need not even be diagonalizable. Thank you so much. I have had this false belief for a long time.

Comment: I have a **vague** question on your example, which may be too naive due to my ignorance. Is your example related to the discrete Fourier transform in some way?

Comment: You're welcome! No, not that I'm aware of

Comment: The representation you give here is even unitary, with respect to the standard Hermitian product of C^2.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Adding, just for the sake of completeness, that the eigenspaces of this particular $T$ are also irreducible submodules, and obviously mapped to themselves. The catch is mostly that when there are several isomorphic irreducible summands, we can find examples like this. Nevertheless, as this answer shows, and intertwiner need not be diagonalizable, and then it is more complicated.

Comment: The decomposition promised by Maschke is not unique in the sense that the subspaces $V_i$ would be uniquely identified. They are only unique up to shuffling of the components.

Comment: Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen: , these are interesting considerations. I am adding a couple of related comments to the main text. (It is a bit unfortunate that this website discourages discussion, promoting the Q&A style instead.)